# Reproducing Music App's NavigationBar Animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, tableview, navigationbar

In my project I want to achieve a very similar animation like in the Artist-ViewController of the stock Music App.

When the `UITableView` scrolls to a specific offset the navigationBar's `tintColor`, the color of the title and the color of the statusbar changes.

To achieve that I added an `UIView` (I named it `containerView`) as a `subView` of the `UINavigationBar` and inside that `containerView` I added a `UIBlurEffect`. Now when the tableView scrolls I am listening to `scrollViewDidScroll` to change the earlier named attributes which works really good.

```
 containerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: -(statusBarHeight), width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: frame.height + statusBarHeight)
 containerView.clipsToBounds = true

 insertSubview(containerView, at: 0)

 let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .extraLight)
 overlayView.effect = blurEffect
 overlayView.backgroundColor = unOverlayColor

 let height = frame.height + statusBarHeight

 overlayView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: containerView.frame.height, width: containerView.frame.width, height: height)

 containerView.addSubview(overlayView)
```

My only problem is that the `containerView` is placed above the `UINavigationBar's navigationItems` and therefore hides them.
So my question is how can I add the `containerView` behind the navigationItems to the `UINavigationBar`?

I figured out that it has to be something with the way how navigationBars are handled in iOS 11 because on iOS 10 everything works fine.